# Mahout Naive Bayes CSV Classification

Tags: java, csv, mahout, document-classification

I have these 2 CSV files:

1. train-set.csv
2. test-set.csv

Both of them are in the same structure (with different content) and similar to this example :

[image]

Each column is a feature and the last column - `class`, is the name of the class to predict.

.

**Can anyone please provide a sample code for:**

2. Initializing Naive Bayes with a CSV file (model creation, training, required pre-processing, etc...)
3. For a given CSV row - predicting a class

Thanks!

.

.

BTW -

I'm using `Mahout 0.9` and `Hadoop 2.4` and iv'e already tried to follow these links:

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/y0uRZw9Q4iHdjrm4Rfsu
http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/using-the-mahout-naive-bayes-classifier-to-automatically-classify-twitter-messages/

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Managed to create a working example.

if you are interested, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Jossef/e6c8fc0c31f0c2bf036a)

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. I need to do something like this and didn't know how to get started. Just one question, were you getting good results with this model?

Comment: i got negative results from my csv model due to const 0 columns

Comment: @DivyangShah there is. look at the bottom of `MahoutTest.java`

Comment: hello, Jossef is there any mahout library available for this classification?

Comment: @littletiger, have you tried the link in the answer?

Comment: Hi, I copy your code in github to my eclipse and download the required jar. Now, the compile is OK. But I don't know how to use your code in mahout. Which command line should I use? If I put your code into a jar called mahouttest.jar?

Comment: I tried your code, I think I added all the required jar. But still get this exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544415/mahout-intdoubleprocedure-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: Hi, Thanks Jossef,I missed some jar.I finally solved my problem. Now your code can build successfully. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jossef Harush But when I using kdd cup 99 data,the 10% data. Got the following result. features: 39.0
labels: 23
400000 : 0 : 400000 0.0. Why return 39 instead of 41?