# Mahout IntDoubleProcedure NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop, noclassdeffounderror, mahout

I'm using my school's server which already have hadoop and mahout.
But I need to parse csv to vector. So I tried someone else code from git.
But I got the following exception which I can't solve.

```
dcmac04:dir username$ java -jar BigDataNaiveBayes_fat.jar 
May 30, 2015 1:48:17 AM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using    builtin-java classes where applicable
May 30, 2015 1:48:17 AM org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool getCompressor
INFO: Got brand-new compressor

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
 org/apache/mahout/math/function/IntDoubleProcedure
  at NaiveBayes.CsvToVectors.vectorize(CsvToVectors.java:53)
  at NaiveBayes.MahoutTest.csv2vectors(MahoutTest.java:53)
  at NaiveBayes.MahoutTest.main(MahoutTest.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.function.IntDoubleProcedure
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  ... 3 more
```

Thank you very much.

My jar has already including mahout-math...jar and mahout-core...jar and some other jar.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the package mahout-collections-1.0.jar.